# Android ldpi device should use mdpi resource?

Tags: android, resources, dpi

I have published an app which have an mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi image for the app icon.
I have received some feedback that on ldpi devices my icon wasn't used and the default one from android is used.

Why is that ? My app has a drawable-ldpi folder but it is empty. Should I delete it ? Is this specific to the launcher icon ?

EDIT : I don't have any image in the drawable folder, only xml shape or selector. I have see this issue with a ldpi screen of 240 x 320 pixels (Samsung Galaxy Y running Android 2.3.6).
I'm talking about this application : http://code.google.com/p/morpion-1vs1/ (the code is public because otherwise I should pay for the repository, I know the activities are a bit messy)

Here is the icon used : [image]

Answer (score 2):

Put a 36x36 pixel size version of your application launcher icon "j5oDi.png" into "drawable-ldpi".

---

The Launcher icon sizes are described here: [Launcher Icons -> Size and Format](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html)

You should have icon files in each of those resource folders at various sizes:

- res/drawable-ldpi (120 dpi - Low density screen): **36x36** px
- res/drawable-mdpi (160 dpi - Medium density screen): **48x48** px
- res/drawable-hdpi (240 dpi - High density screen): **72x72** px
- res/drawable-xhdpi (320 dpi - Extra-high density screen): **96x96** px.

Comment: I know that. You wrote "you should have icon files", but should I or am I obliged to specify one for each density ? Why isn't Android using the mdpi resources like it does for every other image ?

Comment: Android is willing to up-rez a small image for a higher density device, but unwilling to down-rez a larger image for a smaller density device (i.e. unwilling to use your MDPI image on a LDPI device). It thinks there would be too much overhead in opening a bigger image than the device is designed for (remember, the device must open potentially many images just like yours when it displays the applications folder if there are a lot of apps). The safe road is to display the default correct size Android icon if you have not provided the correct-or-smaller app icon. This may differ between LDPI devs

Comment: Hi Stephane. I just browsed through your source. I see the icon file is called 'ic_launcher.png'. I think you should make a 36x36 copy of this file and copy it to the 'drawable-ldpi' folder. To answer your earlier question, in this case I think you are "obliged".

Comment: Reminder to upvote (triangle) and accept (check) helpful and correct answers.